# Does this class act in the same way of its parent?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I define a template class like this:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class SomeThing
{
    ~~~
};
```

and I want to use `SomeThing<X, Y>`. Then that isn't neat, so I did this:

```
typedef SomeThing<X, Y> SomeNewThing;
```

However, I have some problem yet. The forwarding declaration of SomeNewThing will be this form.

```
class X;
class Y;
template <typename A, typename B> class SomeThing;
typedef SomeThing<X, Y> SomeAppropriateNewName;
```

It is inconvenient to write this in every header that contains this class.
So, rather than using of typedef, I try using inheritance.

```
class SomeAppropriateNewName : public Something<X, Y> {};
```

Except inheritance, it is just an empty class. The forward declaration will be like this.

```
class SomeAppropriateNewName;
```

It seems like everything should work correctly.

Does `SomeNewThing` act in exactly same way that `SomeThing<X, Y>` do?

Does this class act in the same way of its parent?
Isn't there any difference?

Comment: I like this idea and I'm also curious if that may cause any problems - IMHO not really - the only problem I'd see might be that the size of class SomeAppropriateNewName will be slightly bigger.

Comment: why not write the typedef in one single header and include that header in every other header? Preferably in the header with class SomeThing

Comment: @Cresis is right... further, if the header file defining the template is too bulky for all clients to include directly, create a forward-declaration header `something_fwd.h` that just has the declaration: it should live alongside `something.h` in the filesystem, be included first by `something.h`, and be "owned" by the maintainer(s) of `something.h`.  For precedent/example, consider the Standard `<iosfwd>` header, which has forward-declarations of content from `<iostream>`.

Comment: Any arguments against it, guys?

Comment: @Iisu: sure... it can be a pain to forward the constructor calls unless you're already on C++11, you've got the old and often more theoretical than practical issues of a `new SomeAppropriateNewName` pointer potential deleted as a `Something<X, Y>*` (unless `Something` has a virtual destructor), you risk bloat from templates being instantiated for both `SomeAppropriateNewName` and `Something<X, Y>`, functions returning `Something<X, Y>` can't be assigned to `SomeAppropriateNewName`s without an extra bridging `operator=` - similar for copy-construction; you can miss traits [+more/out of space].

Comment: So essentialy one would have to implement constructor invoking base class ctor and virtual dtor, which in turn creates vtable and the whole thing might get sligtly bigger. Good points, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SomeAppropriateNewName` has a few differences.  Some of which you can fix.

`SomeAppropriateNewName` should forward constructors and other special member functions to its parent.

If you delete a `SomeAppropriateNewName *` as a `Something<X, Y> *` you invoke undefined behavior without a `virtual` destructor.  In practice, if `SomeAppropriateNewName` is empty everything may be fine.

`SomeAppropriateNewName` does not pattern-match template overloads like `Something<X, Y>` does.  It is a distinct type.  It will work pretty well with function argument matching (there are slight differences), but if you pass it to:

```
template<class T> struct is_something:std::false_type{};
template<class X, class Y> struct is_something<Something<X,Y>>:std::true_type{};
```

then `Something<X, Y>` gives true, while `SomeAppropriateNewName` gives false.

Round-tripping to `void*` has to go to the exact same type, unless both types are standard layout I think.

Comment: Then, if I make ctor and virtual dtor, and I don' use the template form at all, does it has any problem?

Comment: @snow other than `void*` round tripping?  Dtor makes it definitely not standard layout.  And you need to forward constructors and assignment operators (either implicitly or explicitly): how to do that perfectly deserves its own question.